# how to access controller method with the given url

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel framework. I need to access controller method with the name of the given url. My routes code look like below :

```
   <?php
      Route::get('home','HomeController@showWelcome');
   ?>
```

HomeController.php look like this

```
   <?php

     class HomeController extends BaseController {
        public function showWelcome()
       {
          return View::make('hello');
       }
     }

   ?>
```

My problem is can't able to access the method of showWelcome while giving the url like **http://example.com/home**

But i can able to access with the url **http://example.com/index.php/home**

How to sove this issue.. can anyone help me to do this..Thanks in advance.

.htaccess file look like below :

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
 </IfModule>

 RewriteEngine On

 # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

 # Handle Front Controller...
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

 </IfModule>
```

Comment: What do you see when you access http://example.com/home ? Any errors?

Comment: yes.. i got the error like **The requested URL /example.com/home was not found on this server.**.. But if i do like **/example.com/index.php/home** means it should work..

Comment: OK, so you see default SERVER 404 page - not Laravel 404 page? This  tells that the problem is in .htaccess file or your server vhost configuration. Have you made any changes in .htaccess?

Comment: people start using frameworks before knowing any basics and stuff...

Comment: @violator667: Nothing i changed in that .htaccess file.... I will post my .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment,but I don't have enough reputation now.

This is a rewrite problem,have a look at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls to check out you have right configuration.

If you are using apache and your .htaccess doesn't work,it's because the mod_rewrite is turned off.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this does qualify as an answer. Maybe add a code sample or quote from the page you linked.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should turned on mod_rewrite.

If it does not work, then edit `public/.htaccess` and try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: could you please tell me that where i have to turn on mod_rewrite

Comment: Please open httpd.conf file from `apache\apache2.4.9\conf`. Then find this line: `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`. just remove "#". So the line will be: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Comment: Great!! Just click  Wamp Server control panel, then "Apache", then "Apache Modules". From the list click rewrite_module. Thats it.

Comment: @ Feroj Bepari: still it's not working.. am trying to do that only. Once i get it, surely will accept it..